# JAVA - return statement within the for loop

Tags: java, return

I have a simple question about the "return" statement.  Example is in the code.
I always think the isPrime(n) is always "true". Because the "return true;" is at the end of the method, it should over-write previous returns. Any one can help? The codes are running perfect, producing the right results.

```
private boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for(int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) return false;   
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

'return' exits the function returning whatever value you return. The last return is never reached so it won't return the default value.

Comment: Thanks. So it doesn't matter the 'return' is in a loop or not.

Comment: It does, if it is prime then it returns false, exiting the whole function. break would just exit the for loop (this would always return true if you did this). return is more powerful returning a value to the parent/calling function.

Answer (score 1):

No, once you return from a method, you're done.  If you want to convince yourself, insert print statements, or run it through a debugger.

Comment: I did.0-true
1-true
2-true
3-true
4-false
5-true
6-false
7-true
8-false
9-false
10-false

Answer (score 1):

If `if (n % i == 0)` is true it executes `return false;` and will exit the method. `return true;` will only be reached if `return false;` can't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

No, a second `return` does not override an earlier one, it is never even reached. Control leaves the method immediately upon `return`.

(The only way for that not to happen would be to have a second `return` inside of a `finally` block. That would indeed change the return value. But is is highly discouraged)

Answer (score 0):

Functions don't fully execute and then return, they can exit at any point during the execution with a return statement.

So if a number is found to `n % i == 0` then the subroutine will return false and exit.

If the function completed the `for` loop and never resolved the `if` statement it returns true and exits.