# Return a boolean from a method that searches an array

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop, boolean

Is there a way to immediately return a boolean when a condition is met during a for loop that is scanning through a list?

I've been using this "flag" method when doing these kinds of things.

The class referred to by `this` is an object that is made up of multiple `Point` objects.

This method returns `true` if any one of the `Point` objects in its `pointsCovered` ArrayList is equal to the Point `p` passed into the method (if the object *contains* the input point, hence the method name).

```
boolean containsPoint(Point p) {

    boolean flag = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    {
        if (pointsCovered.get(i).equals(p)) {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return flag;
}
```

I can't find anything similar to this by searching.

Basically I'm asking if there's a better or standard way of doing this.

Edit: For clarification, I was using this `flag` variable because I didn't know that returning a statement in a `for` loop would terminate the loop and immediate return the value.

Cheers.

Comment: Why not simply `return true;` inside your `if`?

Comment: Have a look at [return in for loop or outside loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800195/return-in-for-loop-or-outside-loop) or [Does returning a value break a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661081/java-does-returning-a-value-break-a-loop) or [return statement within the for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880348/java-return-statement-within-the-for-loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the `flag` completely and `return` asap:

```
boolean containsPoint(Point p) {

    for (int i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    {
        if (pointsCovered.get(i).equals(p)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: So a return statement will immediately terminate the method no matter where it occurs?

Comment: @Josh in almost all cases: yes. *If* you `return` from within a `try` block with a `finally` block that block will still be executed but that should not concern you here.

Comment: @Josh "no matter where it occurs" it won't terminate the method if the return is inside a lambda or a method in a locally-defined class.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check the entire collection, you can do this in one line:

```
boolean containsPoint(Point p) {
    return pointsCovered.contains(p);
}
```

Comment: +1, but this is a) assuming it is a `Collection` (it looks like it is); b) `pointsCovered.size() == this.length`; c) various other subtle assumptions about the implementations of the classes.

Comment: Wow, that's useful. I'm only two semesters into coding so there's a lot of useful methods I haven't learned yet.